# Find initial temperature of ideal gas when heated by 400K and volume doubles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

An ideal gas in a flask is heated by $400K$ and expands its volume by the factor $2$. The final pressure equals the initial pressure.

I want to calculate the initial temperature $T_0$.

As the gas is ideal and pressure is constant I have $\frac{V_0}{T_0}=\frac{V_1}{T_1} \Rightarrow T_0=\frac{V_1T_1}{V_0}$ and because $V_1=2V_0$ I have $T_0=\frac{2V_0T_1}{V_0} \Rightarrow T_0=2T_1$ and finally $T_0=2(T_0+400K)$.

Can I find the initial temperature $T_0$ in $K$ which does not contain $T_0$ itself? Is this even correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: HINT -- $T_{0} = \frac{1}{2} T_{1}$

Comment: i dont really get the hint